# ¿Cómo hacer un (“parent > child”).click() si tengo un <select><option>?

Tags: html, jquery

Necesito lanzar un evento .click cuando se haga click en alguna option de un select.

Me refiero a algo como esto:

```js
$("select.diat > option").click(function(){alert("hola");});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="diat">
  <option value="Lunes">Lunes</option>
  <option value="Martes">Martes</option>
  <option value="Miercoles">Miércoles</option>
  <option value="Jueves">Jueves</option>
  <option value="Viernes">Viernes</option>
  <option value="Sabado">Sábado</option>
  <option value="Domingo">Domingo</option>
</select>
```

Me basé en esta documentación: https://api.jquery.com/child-selector/. Ahí hacen algo como lo que quiero, sólo que con una lista.

¿Alguna idea para hacer que esto funcione?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El evento tiene que estar asociado al `<select>` padre, no a los hijos.

El evento para cuando se cambia el valor del select es [**`.change()`**](https://api.jquery.com/change/), que también te va a permitir capturar cambios realizados con el teclado (algo que no se dispara con `.click()`).

```js
$("select.diat").change(function(){
  console.log("Se seleccionó: " , $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<select class="diat">
  <option value="Lunes">Lunes</option>
  <option value="Martes">Martes</option>
  <option value="Miercoles">Miércoles</option>
  <option value="Jueves">Jueves</option>
  <option value="Viernes">Viernes</option>
  <option value="Sabado">Sábado</option>
  <option value="Domingo">Domingo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: gracias, es lo que buscaba!

Comment: Me alegro que te sirviera. Te recomiendo también leer [la respuesta de Alvaro](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31490/127), para terminar de entender cómo funciona `.click()` (y votarla +1 también)

Answer (score 4):

Que yo sepa, el evento `click` no funciona para la etiqueta `option` (por experiencia pasada, como se muestran los `option` depende de cada navegador y tiene bastante truco), aunque podría estar equivocado.

Lo que puedes hacer es controlar el evento `click` del `select` en sí, pero eso va a presentar algunos problemas: no sólo se lanzará cuando se pulse en una opción, sino también cuando se pulsa en la lista para que se despliegue (y puede que eso no es algo que quieras). Otro problema es que si el usuario utiliza el teclado en lugar del ratón, este evento no se disparará.

Otra opción sería controlar el evento `change` también del `select`, pero esa opción también tiene un problema: si se pulsa sobre la misma opción que ya está seleccionada, no se lanza nada. Además, también se lanzaría incluso si no se pulsa en una opción (por ejemplo si el usuario utiliza el teclado para cambiar las opciones)

Aquí te dejo una opción escuchando el evento `click` del `select`:

```js
$(".diat").on("click", function() {
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="diat">
  <option value="Lunes">Lunes</option>
  <option value="Martes">Martes</option>
  <option value="Miercoles">Miércoles</option>
  <option value="Jueves">Jueves</option>
  <option value="Viernes">Viernes</option>
  <option value="Sabado">Sábado</option>
  <option value="Domingo">Domingo</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la aclaración, tendré muy en cuenta lo del select pues necesitaré filtrar si el usuario usa el teclado, tal vez un e.preventDefault() sea conveniente pero eso es harina de otro costal.